# Graphical Layout Raise Problem

Tags: android, eclipse

yesterday i have update my avd at that time internet connection are disconnect.and i got a problem in Build & run project.so simple i have Clean it. and its goes to working fine but when i open **any** xml file it will give message like **"LayoutLib is too recent. Update your tool!"** i think that any tools are missing it will update shortly.but not getting any update. and in any project while i have open project it will give message again this.

i have attach one screen short please consider it and tell me what is the problem?

[image]

Note: *this is not a xml file problem it is globally eclips or plugins problem*

Comment: did you actually updated the tools? via android sdk manager? and the plugins?

Comment: yes i have update it and i loos my connection of internet and i got problem

Comment: and today i have update my sdk which i want but error cant solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your SDK in eclipse, by going to **Window>preferences >Available packages** select the latest package and download

**EDITED**

In the "Graphical Layout" tab of the layout editor there is a dropdown(above theme) for selecting the Android version to use.  so select a compatible version and you're probably good to go.

Comment: are you talking about Editing Config ? then i have also try it with different different screen -1

Comment: not screen layout, see there is dropdown box which let you choose android version (API)